# Laravel 5 Array with key save in model

Tags: php, arrays, model, laravel-5

Have array which have ***key & value***. The keys name are same database columns name.

***Total of keys in an index is greater than  50.***

- So,**not possible to save data  one by one key  like**

  ```
  $user = new User;

  $user->name = 'John';
  ..........
  .......
  .......so on

  $user->save();
  ```

**Sample array:**

```
Array
(
    [name] => 'Amit',
    [age] => 25,
    [field1] => 'val1',
    ....
  [field33] => 'how'    ,
....
   [field54] => 'sumit'     
)
```

*Now, my question is that how can i save data in an model using easiest process*.

### Info:

- Using laravel 5

### Try:

```
$Plan=new Plans;
 $Plan->fill( $array);
 $Plan->save();
```

***Note:*** *I know that fill not working as it  not defined at  fillable variable of that   model*

Comment: Fill not working because the fillable variable is not defined? And why don't you define it?

Comment: Can you describe why you don't want to use the `fillable` attribute?

Comment: as there are lot colums that why i does not want to define fillable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Eloquent` model has encapsulated the attributes of the object. So you can only alter/set them through the `set` (`$model->attribute`) or the `fill(array $attributes)` method. All the Eloquent methods that mass assign the attributes is using the method `fill()`.

So there are 2 ways to insert new Eloquent based models with an array in the database, one that uses the `fill()` method and one that doens't.

### Method 1: Mass assignment

Add the attribute `protected $fillable = [ 'column_a', 'column_b', .. ];` to your model. Then you can use the mass assignment like this.

```
$Plan = new Plans;
$Plan->fill( $array );
$Plan->save();
```

Or you can use:

```
$plan = Plans::create( $array );
```

### Method 2: QueryBuilder::insert( array )

If you don't have any `boot` methods registered on `creating` and `created` (DB won't trigger these) then you also can use the `QueryBuilder` to insert the rows in the database.

```
// insert one plan
DB::table('plans')->insert([ $array ]);
$plan = Plans::find( DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId() );

// insert multiple plans in one query
$plans = [ $plan_a_arr, $plan_b_arr, .. ];
DB::table('plans')->insert( $plans );
```

Comment: thank for u answer.I does not follow  method.Is there any other  process with out fill();

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. The 2nd method is not using the `fill()` method.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you don't want to define the database columns/array keys in `$fillable` attribute of your model, as it is a just a one-time task and then you would be able to do this simply:

```
$plan = Plans::create( $array );
```

Another way, if you have all the data in an associative array with keys matching to the columns in DB table, which you do, is to use a foreach loop:

```
$plan = new Plans;
foreach( $array as $key => $value )
{
    $plan->$key = $value;
}
$plan->save();
```