# Laravel/Lumen/Eloquent - Update coretable::with($OneDimArrayOfTablenames) with multidimensional array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, lumen

I want to write a function where a multidimensional array with the following structure:

```php
    {
      "id_coretable": 1,
      "Internal_key": "UPDATED1",
      "extensiontable_itc": {
        "description_itc": "UPDATED1"
      },
      "extensiontable_sysops": {
        "description_sysops": "UPDATED1"
      }
    }
```

updates a multidimensional model/collection (i can create either of them, whatever the actual solution to this problem might require) with basically the same structure:

```php
    {
      "id_coretable": 1,
      "Internal_key": "NOTYETUPDATED1",
      "extensiontable_itc": {
        "description_itc": "NOTYETUPDATED1"
      },
      "extensiontable_sysops": {
        "description_sysops": "NOTYETUPDATED1"
      }
    }
```

This model was fetched like this:

```php
$model = coretable::with($OneDimArrayOfTablenames);
```

I've already searched stackoverflow for questions regarding the updating of a model with input in the form of an array. I found a rather effective solution here:

> [Laravel 5 Array with key save in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411465/laravel-5-array-with-key-save-in-model)

See the accepted answer there.

However:

```php
    $model->fill($twoDimArrayWithUpdates);
    $model->save();
```

Does not do the job. 
It only updates the elements from the outer array, namely `Internal_key`.
It does not "descend" deeper into the target array, and maybe it also doesn't even descend deeper into the source array. I don't really know how to observe this closer though^^

Can I do something about this?
In the declaration of the models of the affected tables, I made the attributes to which these updates shall be mass assigned:

```php
      protected $fillable = [
        'name_of_the_attribute'
      ];
```

So I guess this should not be the problem.
If you require more info about my DB structure or the model, just tell me. 
I just tried to keep this question as focussed as possible and so far I dont think you need anything else.