# Iterating over Model with foreach produces strange results - Lumen/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, lumen

I want to iterate over a model with this structure:

```
{
  "id_coretable": 1,
  "Internal_key": "UPDATED1",
  "extensiontable_itc": {
    "description_itc": "UPDATED1"
  },
  "extensiontable_sysops": {
    "description_sysops": "UPDATED1"
  }
}
```

It was retrieved with this code:

```
$join = coretable::with($permittedTables)->find(1);
```

Where `$permittedTables` is an array of tablenames.

Now, when I do this:

```
foreach($join as $el){
  log::info($el);
}
```

I get these results:

```
[2020-02-06 11:32:36] local.INFO: 1  
[2020-02-06 11:32:36] local.INFO: 1  
[2020-02-06 11:32:36] local.INFO:   
[2020-02-06 11:32:36] local.INFO: 1
```

Why is that? According to the Laravel docs, iterating over a COLLECTION should definitely work:

```
$users = App\User::where('active', 1)->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections

Now, I definitely have a Model here, not a collection. I checked it with `if(...instanceof model)`.
However, when I force retrieving a collection by using `->findMany(1)` instead of `->find(1)` then things dont really get better. 
Using the collection on the foreach loop only causes to foreach loop to output full structure once and then leave the loop. If I now use this object inside a nested foreach loop, then I get the same results again as above.

Is this the normal behavior of laravel? 
And if so, is there any way to iterate over a model, especially a "2D-Model" like here?

Bottomline:
What I ultimately want to achieve is being able to "dynamically" assign new values to any of the elements of the model, and then persist it to the DB. 
If for this purpose I should overwrite the nested "arrays" inside the model with new arrays, then so be it, just tell me how to do it xD 
The input which is supposed to update the model will have the EXACT same structure and indexes as the model. 
You can also read about this in my other question here:
[Laravel/Lumen/Eloquent - Update coretable::with($OneDimArrayOfTablenames) with multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60092037/laravel-lumen-eloquent-update-coretablewithonedimarrayoftablenames-with-m)

I'm currently just trying to approach the solution bit by bit, since this question above hasnt received any answers. And the first thing that came to my mind was trying to iterate the model and update it element by element. But as you can see, I'm also running into problems on that one as well..^^

Comment: You want to iterate over a model, or its relationships that you pass into with()? If it’s first, then you need to re-read documentation about the find method with single argument in the link you provided. Passing 1 in argument means it will return you a single model instance whose primary key is 1.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Well, I want to iterate over the full model you see in my OP. This is the result of a fetch from a coretable, which is referenced by extensiontables via FK and which was joined with these tables using coretable::with($arrayOfTablenames). Alongside the record from coretable which has the ID "1", the records from the extensiontables referencing this records are present in this model as well. And I want to be able to update all of them by iterating over this model.